# Linker error in c program

Tags: c, winapi, linker-errors

I am trying to code c program that uses Win32 api to display message box, but i am getting this linker error. How could it be resolved?

code :

```
#include<windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevsInstance,LPSTR SZCmdLine,int iCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("hello"),TEXT("this is me"),MB_ICONEXCLAMATION |  MB_OK);
   return 0;
}
```

error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: winfirstprog, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>winfirstprog.cpp
1>Linking...
1>winfirstprog.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000030) "extern "C" int __stdcall MessageBoxW(struct HWND__ *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?MessageBoxW@@$$J216YGHPAUHWND__@@PB_W1I@Z) referenced in function "extern "C" int __cdecl MessageBox(struct HWND__ *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?MessageBox@@$$J0YAHPAUHWND__@@PB_W1I@Z)
1>winfirstprog.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __stdcall MessageBoxW(struct HWND__ *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?MessageBoxW@@$$J216YGHPAUHWND__@@PB_W1I@Z) referenced in function "extern "C" int __cdecl MessageBox(struct HWND__ *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?MessageBox@@$$J0YAHPAUHWND__@@PB_W1I@Z)
1>F:\my_doc\C programming Prog & Documentation\Data structure in c\STARTOVER\winfirstprog\Debug\winfirstprog.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://f:\my_doc\C programming Prog & Documentation\Data structure in c\STARTOVER\winfirstprog\winfirstprog\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>winfirstprog - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You might like to tell the linker to link `User32.lib`, as the latter implements `MessageBox*()`.

Comment: Are you using C++ by intention? Passing .cpp files to VC makes it run as C++ compiler. C++ is differnt from C.

Comment: Getting started with the correct project template is 99% of the Hello World problems.  You didn't, this code got compiled by the C++/CLI compiler.  File + New Project and select the Win32 + Win32 Project template.

Comment: thanks Hans Passant , you solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Getting started with the correct project template is 99% of the Hello World problems. You didn't, this code got compiled by the C++/CLI compiler. File + New Project and select the Win32 + Win32 Project template. – Hans Passant